# Firefox slow when not using PIA VPN

Tags: firefox

Firefox runs great when using PIA VPN. When only connected to my ISP, it is slow to load sites and video can take more than 30 seconds to load.

I have installed IVACY VPN because PIA is going to 64 bit OS CLIENTS and I don't want to upgrade 16.04 32 bit to 64 bit.

When connected to IVACY, Firefox runs as slow as it does with my ISP.

I have tested both VPNs using the same torrent on Deluge and they both have comparable speeds that very high.

I am thinking that the problem resides with Firefox or there was something in the PIA install that is causing Firefox to only work well with PIA.

Looking for help!

Comment: Thinking that your VPN has an ad blocker running, mine does(another VPN).  Can upgrade to 18.04 on 32 bit, but is last time.  Only other thing that comes to mind is the DNS server used.

Comment: If your connection is WiFi, make sure your MTU is 1492 not 1500. `ip link`, and read `man ip ip-link`.

Comment: I would never use a torrent to test speeds its to variable. Use one of the many speed test sites on the internet.